# Same Fontface for Multiple Styles

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

So I have a `base.css` file in my static folder, accompanied by two font files, `Fontin_Sans_R_45b.otf` and `Fontin_Sans_SC_45b.otf`, for regular and small-caps styles, respectively. I want to define fontfaces for both styles, so I've done the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'FontinSans';
    src:url('Fontin_Sans_R_45b.otf');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:'FontinSans';
    src:url('Fontin_Sans_SC_45b.otf');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:small-caps;
}
```

I have triple checked the file names and their locations. Yet when I try to load my page, I get this error for the small-caps font in Firefox:

```
[12:17:27.211] downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontinSans" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): status=2147500037
source: file:///Users/user/Documents/DjangoProjects/blogEngineEnv/blogEngine/blogApp/static/css/Fontin_Sans_SC_45b.otf @ file:///Users/user/Documents/DjangoProjects/blogEngineEnv/blogEngine/blogApp/static/css/base.css
```

What am I doing wrong? Aside from not anticipating IE messiness -- this is just a quick prototype I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

You do have an error in your declaration.
`small-caps` is not a `font-style`, it's a `font-variant`!

Not sure if that is the cause of the error though. I'd expect a faulty property to be ignored. However, you never know.